# Class AppBundle has no association named

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am relatively new to Doctrin 2 and Symfony 3 and picking up a project. I'm having trouble working on a mapping issue when I create a custom class.

In short when I run the following:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Repository;

    /**
     * FormRepository
     *
     * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
     * repository methods below.
     */
    class FormRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    {
        public function findWithDocId($id, $clientId=null) {
            $docId = '2342';

            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
            $query->join('f.documentVersion', 'dv');
            $query->where('dv.doc_id = :docId')->setParameter('docId', $docId);
            $query->andWhere('f.id = :id')->setParameter('id',$id);
            return $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
"cls": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",
  "errors": [
    "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 67 near 'dv WHERE dv.doc_id': Error: Class AppBundle\\Entity\\Form has no association named documentVersion"
```

My Form Entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\AccessorOrder;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FormRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="forms")
 * @AccessorOrder("custom", custom = {"id"})
 */
class Form {

  ......


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DocumentVersion", inversedBy="form")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="doc_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @SerializedName("document_version")
     * @Groups({"form_details_document"})
     */
    private $document;

  ......

}
```

And my Document Version Entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="document_versions")
 */
class DocumentVersion {

   .....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Form", mappedBy="document", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"document_versions"})
     */
    private $form;
.....
```

Can any one help me in what I am doing wrong? Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `private $document;` in form to hold the documentVersion entity so:

```
$query->join('f.documentVersion', 'dv');
```

Should be the name of that property:

```
$query->join('f.document', 'dv');
```

Basically the error:

> Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Form has no association named
>   documentVersion

Is saying im trying to access documentVersion on entity Form but I cant find it/its getter/setter

Comment: Ahhh thanks this makes sense now. I was thinking in SQL where you join the tables but it is not. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah doctrine takes a different mindset, you basically have to forget SQL all together and think in objects. Also if you can spare 25 a month or just once I found knpuniversity tutorials on symfony3/doctrine very useful to get me started.

Answer (score 3):

In query builder you should use property names instead of SQL column names.

You have a property:

```
private $document;
```

Therefore instead of:

```
$query->join('f.documentVersion', 'dv');
```

try with:

```
$query->join('f.document', 'dv');
```

Comment: I had read the docs so many times, google this a million times! I didn't see anywhere where it told me to use the variable name instead of the table name! Thanks so much for this!